# Error when starting Vite: "failed to load config from .../vite.config.js error when starting dev server: TypeError: Cannot redefine property: File"

Tags: reactjs, vite

This is my first time starting a vite app.
this is the error shown when i run dev.

```
failed to load config from /home/amaljith/CI-Project/vite.config.js
error when starting dev server:
TypeError: Cannot redefine property: File
    at Function.defineProperty (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/amaljith/CI-Project/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/index.js:7:8)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1241:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1295:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1091:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:938:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1115:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:130:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/amaljith/CI-Project/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/helpers/config-api.js:16:14)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1241:14)
```

this is the vite.config.js file

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
})
```

these are the version of node and npm

node - 20.6.0
npm - 9.8.1

```
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.15",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.3",
    "eslint": "^8.45.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.3",
    "vite": "^4.4.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: This is an identified issue upstream issue with node with no resolution.  You'll have to downgrade node for now https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/15927

Answer (score 0):

The error appears to be rooted in Babel, which is a compiler/transpiler that translate code from JSX to Javascript (I think?). Luckily, Vite has an additional transpiler as of this year (SWC), which is a rust-based transpiler that is 20x faster than Babel!

To start a Vite project with SWC, I did the following:

1. npm install vite@latest

Then, it prompts you...

Project title: Chess
Program name: package.json
Language: React

THEN, it offers you 4 options, and one of them is Javascript w/ SWC (the last option).

Now, npm run dev opens a server (quite fast!) that I'm able to work on.

If other folks have an answer to the original problem, please let me know!

Answer (score -1):

I change my node version to 18, you can try

Comment: And... did that solve the problem? Please read [answer].